# why am i getting this incorrect entry pop up but my php file executes login successfully

Tags: php, typescript, ionic3

Why am i getting this incorrect entry pop up but my php file executes login successfully. its confusing where file should i edit is it the ts file or the php file i need some eyes and brains to fix this code I've provided i need you guys. I hope you guys takes time to help everyone especially those who don't have much knowledge of ionic3 as this framework don't have much resources to learn it deeply thankyou for your future answers.

login.html

```
<ion-list style="padding: 50px">
      <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="username" #username></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" name="userpass" #userpass></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

        <div style="padding-top: 50px ">
        <button ion-button  block (click)="signIn()">Sign In</button>
        <button ion-button  outline block (click)="RegisterPage()">Register</button>
        </div>
      </ion-list>
```

login.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  @ViewChild("username") username;
  @ViewChild("userpass") userpass;

  data: string;
  items: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              private http: Http, 
              public loading: LoadingController
              ) 
              {

              }

  RegisterPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage)
  }

  signIn() {

    //// check to confirm the username and userpass fields are filled

    if (this.username.value == "") {

      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

        title: "ATTENTION",
        subTitle: "Username field is empty",
        buttons: ['OK']
      });

      alert.present();
    } else

    if (this.userpass.value == "") {

      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

        title: "ATTENTION",
        subTitle: "Password field is empty",
        buttons: ['OK']
      });

      alert.present();

    } else {

      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
      });

      let data = {
        username: this.username.value,
        userpass: this.userpass.value
      };

      let loader = this.loading.create({
        content: 'Processing please wait...',
      });

      loader.present().then(() => {

        this.http.post('http://localhost/8990API/login.php', data, options)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res)
            loader.dismiss()
            if (res.status == "Login successfully") {

              let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: "CONGRATS",
                subTitle: (res.message),
                buttons: ['OK']
              });

              alert.present();
              this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, data);
              this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
            } 
            else {
              let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: "Incorrect entry please try again.",
                subTitle: (res.message),
                buttons: ['OK']
              });
              alert.present();
            }
          });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

login.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400'); // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    }

    exit(0);
}

require "dbconnect.php";

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
if (isset($data)) {
    $request = json_decode($data,true);
    if (!empty($request) && isset($request['username'], $request['userpass'])) {
        $username = $request['username'] ?? '';
        $userpass = $request['userpass'] ?? '';
        $userpass = sha1($userpass."@la]#}^(dy*%-Ga=/,Ga!.");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM useraccount WHERE username = '$username' and userpass = '$userpass'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if ($result && ($count = mysqli_num_rows($result)) > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            // $active = $row['active'];
            $status = "success";
            $message = "Login successfully";
        } 
        else {
            $status = "fail";
            $message = "Your Login Username or Password is invalid";
        }
    }
    else {
        $status = "fail";
        $message = "You must specify a Username and Password";
    }
}
else {
    $status = "fail";
    $message = "You must specify a Username and Password";
}
echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'message' => $message, 'data' => $data));

?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I suppose the question is why is this login script showing a failed login but proceeding to login the user.

Comment: Okay, well I will not flag this as its an ongoing matter you are getting help with but for future reference, you should update the existing question with more information when you are asked for it by another SO user, instead of opening another question with only partial information. You may be getting assistance from one member, but the entire community can view the questions and will rightfully wonder what the question is about. Besides, the other party may not see this and so the question could be left unanswered which is not what anybody wants.

Comment: okay sir i understand will edit this question for everyone

Comment: You need to change `res.status == "Login successfully"` to `res.status == "success"`

Comment: ohh my goodness thankyou so much sir

Comment: i have successfully login

Comment: @Nick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257800/is-there-any-body-here-already-integrated-angular-material-in-ionic3-and-succes

Comment: @MjSaijem good to hear it's working. Unfortunately I don't know anything about angular and ionic so can't help you with your new question. Good luck.

Comment: @Nick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257800/is-there-any-body-here-already-integrated-angular-material-in-ionic3-and-succes

Comment: @MjSaijem read my previous comment...

Comment: ahh okay sir thanks a lot

Comment: @Nick i have a new question sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263654/how-to-display-multiple-data-selected-in-radio-button

Comment: @MjSaijem sorry - same comment applies...

Comment: @Nick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993264/how-to-pass-some-text-or-paragraph-from-a-page-to-another-page

Comment: @Nick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282058/how-can-i-implement-a-switching-image-back-and-forth-using-if-else-statement

Comment: @Nick hi sir a have a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296112/how-to-display-data-from-a-local-json-file-by-clicking-the-button

Comment: @MjSaijem I don't know anything about angular and ionic. Please don't tag me about those questions.