# How to display multiple data selected in radio button?

Tags: ionic3

This is a multi-level accordion menu and at the 3rd level there is a radio button beside every item list. I'm hoping that there is somebody there already did this and can relate to this problem. Please take time to help somebody that is trying there hard to make things happen for their projects as this course doesn't have much resources to study for every problems. Thank you for your future answers guys god bless.

[image]

This is not just a typical radio button all its data is from menu.json that looks like this.

menu.json

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "MAIN",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Main Door",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Painted door lock"
            },
            {
              "name": "Painted door"
            },
            {
              "name": "Damaged door"
            },
            {
              "name": "Damaged door lock"
            },
            {
              "name": "Painted hinge"
            },
            {
              "name": "Stuck door"
            },
            {
              "name": "With gap below"
            },
            {
              "name": "Paint with cracks"
            },
            {
              "name": "Unfinished door paint"
            },
            {
              "name": "Gaps beside door knob"
            },
            {
              "name": "Door with voids"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

from.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-form',
  templateUrl: 'form.html',
})
export class FormPage {
  data: any[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http) {
    let localData = this.http.get('assets/data/menus.json').map(res => res.json().items);
    localData.subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
    });
  }

  toggleSection(i) {
    this.data[i].open = !this.data[i].open;
  }

  toggleItem(i, j) {
    this.data[i].children[j].open = !this.data[i].children[j].open;

  }



  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FormPage');
  }

}
```

form.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list class="accordion-list">
    <!-- first level -->
      <ion-list-header *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index" no-lines no-padding style="margin-bottom: 0%">

          <button ion-item (click)="toggleSection(i)" detail-none [ngClass]="{'section-active': item.open, 'section': !item.open}">
            <ion-icon item-left name="ios-arrow-forward" *ngIf="!item.open"></ion-icon>
            <ion-icon item-left name="ios-arrow-up" *ngIf="item.open"></ion-icon>
            {{ item.name }}
          </button>

            <ion-list *ngIf="item.children && item.open" no-lines style="margin-bottom: 0%">
              <!-- Second Level -->
              <ion-list-header *ngFor="let child of item.children; let j = index" no-padding style="margin-bottom: 0%">
                <!-- Toggle Button -->
                  <button ion-item (click)="toggleItem(i, j)" detail-none class="child-item" *ngIf="child.children" no-padding no-lines>
                    <ion-icon item-left name="add" *ngIf="!child.open"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon item-left name="close" *ngIf="child.open"></ion-icon>
                    {{ child.name }}
                  </button>

            <!-- Direct Add Button -->
            <!-- <ion-item *ngIf="!child.children" detail-none class="child-item" text-wrap no-lines>
              <h2>{{ child.name }}</h2>
              <p text-lowercase>{{ child.information }}</p>
              <button ion-button outline item-end (click)="buyItem(child)">{{ child.price }}</button>
            </ion-item> -->

            <ion-list *ngIf="child.children && child.open">
              <!-- Third-Level -->
              <ion-item *ngFor="let item of child.children" detail-none class="child-item" text-wrap no-lines>
                <ion-label>{{ item.name }}</ion-label>
                <ion-radio  (ionSelect)="selectRad(item)" [value]="item"></ion-radio>
                <!-- <ion-radio slot="end" color="danger" checked></ion-radio> -->

              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>

          </ion-list-header>
        </ion-list>

      </ion-list-header>
    </ion-list>

<div class="issue">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      Problems to be fix
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      All data that is selected from radio button should display here...
    </ion-card-content>
    <button ion-button full (click)="AreaPage()">Submmit</button>
  </ion-card>
</div>

</ion-content>
```

[image]

All data the is selected will be displayed like this

**Problems to be fix**

> Main
>
> Main Door
>
> ```
> PAINTED DOOR 
>
> LOCK PAINTED DOOR
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Could using ion-select instead of ion-list be a solution? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select

ion-select supports multiple items being selected.